# Stop Matlab from treating a 1xn matrix as a column vector

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm very frustrated with MATLAB right now. Let me illustrate the problem. I'm going to use informal notation here.

I have a column cell vector of strings called `B`. For now, let's say `B = {'A';'B';'C';'D'}`.

I want to have a matrix `G`, which is m-by-n, and I want to replace the numbers in `G` with the respective elements of `B`... For example, let's say `G` is `[4 3; 2 1]`

Let's say I have a variable `n` which says how many rows of `G` I want to take out.

When I do `B(G(1:2,:))`, I get what I want `['D' 'C'; 'B' 'A']`

However, if I do `B(G(1:1,:))` I get `['D';'C']` when what I *really* want to get is `['D' 'C']`

I am using `1:n`, and I want it to have the same behavior for `n = 1` as it does for `n = 2` and `n = 3`. Basically, `G` actually is a `n`-by-1500 matrix, and I want to take the top `n` rows and use it as indexes into `B`.

I could use an if statement that transposes the result if `n = 1` but that seems so unnecessary. Is there really no way to make it so that it stops treating my 1-by-n matrix as if it was a column vector?

Answer (score 4):

According to [this post by Loren Shure](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2006/08/09/essence-of-indexing/):

> Indexing with one array C = A(B) produces output the size of B unless both A and B are vectors.
>
> When both A and B are vectors, the number of elements in C is the number of elements in B and with orientation of A.

You are in second case, hence the behaviour you see.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, you need to maintain the output to have as many columns as in `G`. To achieve the same, you can do something like this -

```
out = reshape(B(G(1:n,:)),[],size(G,2))
```

Thus, with n = 1:

```
out = 
    'D'    'C'
```

With n = 2:

```
out = 
    'D'    'C'
    'B'    'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will only happen in 1-d case. In default, matlab will return column vector since it is the way how it stores matrix. If you want a row vector, you could just use transpose. Well in my opinion it should be fine when n > 1.